# How can I create a div which resizes with a window?

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to create a `div` using `css` that resizes with the window.

```
Example:
   #container
    {
      margin: 3em;
    }
   #header {
     height: 100px;
   }
   #main {

   }
   #footer {
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0px;
   }

   container
      header
      main
      footer
```

So when I resize the window, I want `main` to resize with the window while `header` and `footer` staty 100px;

Is there a way to do it using CSS or I will have to use Javascript?

Comment: If you make it a `%` it'll move with the window resize, or if it's `auto`.  Otherwise yeah you have to hook into the resize event and adjust accordingly.

Comment: The resize event doesn't fire when screen resolution changes. I know it's a small fraction of instances where this would happen... but I wouldn't bring it up if it has never happened. YHou keep telling yourself "They pay for my job"... :P

Answer (score 1):

```
   html, body, #container, #main{
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
   }

   #container
    {
     margin: 3em;
     position:relative;
    }
   #header {
     height: 100px;
     position:absolute;
     z-index:1;
   }
   #main {
     position:absolute;
     top:0;
     left:0;

   }
   #footer {
    position:absolute;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0px;
     z-index:1;
   }

html
  body
   container
      header
      main
      footer
```

The above code should give you what you are looking for a #main will cover the whole screen while your 100px tall header and footer sit over the top of it. I'm using this code on my website right now http://patrickarlt.com.

The footer and header site on top of a div that fills the whole screen. You might also want to listen to the resize event to resize items in #main as a user resizes their screen.

This isn't IE 6 safe however, but my site works in IE 7 and 8 last I checked.

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript you can alter your divs on page load. See this article for the details:

[dynamically resizing divs](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/exploring-limits-css-layout)

Answer (score 0):

I've done similar, but use JavaScript to do it for me as well. It's not the most elegant JS but it works. I used this when I had a div that needed to be maximum size, and it had a side bar, top and bottom bar etc. So when the browser window was resized I had to quickly adjust the container div (which was a map).

You want your  markup to look like (I think you have this already):

```
<div id="container">
 <div id="title">Title</div>
 <div id="main"></div>
 <div id="footer></div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
var browserWidth = 0;
var browserHeight = 0;

function getSize() {
  if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' )
  {
    //Non-IE
    isIE = false;
    browserWidth = window.innerWidth;
    browserHeight = window.innerHeight;
  } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
    //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'
    browserWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    browserHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  } else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight ) ) {

    //They're not running IE7 / FireFox2. Older browser. Find some technology
    //to destroy their computer so they're forced to upgrade.
    browserWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
    browserHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
  }
}

function updateMapSize() {
    //IE7 is 21 pixels LESS than FireFox.
    //Pretty much we want to keep the map to the maximum size alloted.
    getSize();
    //top section
    var height = browserHeight - 200;

    document.getElementById("main").style.height = height;
    document.getElementById("container").style.height = browserHeight ;
    document.getElementById("container").style.width= browserWidth ;

    setTimeout("updateMapSize()", 250);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Javascript, use CSS code as below:

#header {
     height: 100px;
    max-height:100px;
   }

# main {
   }

# footer {
    height: 100px;
max-height:100px;
    bottom: 0px;
   }

Comment: I believe he wanted main to be 100% -200px. Main should always be as big as it can. That's what I got from his question.

Comment: Yes i see. Additionally, he wants to keep this top header and footer as 100px height.  
If he wants to keep footer at bottom, you can put position:absolute; it will keep at bottom.

#header { height: 100px; max-height:100px; }


# main {  height:100%; max-height:100%; min-height:100%; }


# footer { height: 100px; max-height:100px; bottom: 0px; position:absolute; }

Comment: as @Ryan mentioned, main has to fill 100% left over space from the header of footer

Comment: this one is reference for you : http://www.electrictoolbox.com/examples/html-css-footer.html